# Recording the video placed in sd card of android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application where i want to record the video placed in sd card of android application,How can i do this,,,

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What have you tried so far? 2. What results did you get? 3. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (no, it's not self-evident, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: I have use mediarecorder class

Answer (score 1):

Exists a topic in android developer describing about this. Don´t forgot to verify if the SD card is mounted. You can do that using the algoritm **below**:

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState() == android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
 //TODO Your code here.
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media